# I am having some problems using the map function with onPress functionality inside the rendered element

Tags: react-native

I have a map function calling the function `Item` to produce multiple Tiles rendered with `TouchableOpacity`. The `onPress` functionality to navigate to another screen is not working on the Tiles.

I have tried:
Writing an app for a start up.

1. putting a random button which executes the `onPress` function and it worked.
2. using an arrow declaration for the `onPress` and use `this.props.navigation.navigate(''')` got an error saying `this.props.navigation` is undefined. I tried binding the function or setting a state variable navigate to this.props.navigation and it gave me an error of navigate is undefined.
3. I have tried putting random `TouchableOpacity` inside the `scrollview` and navigating when clicking them worked

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  NestedScrollView,
  Button,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';
// import Tiles from '../elements/Tiles'
import { Tile} from 'react-native-elements'
import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");



class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation
    this.state = {
      navigation: this.props.navigation,
      tiles: [
                    {"key":1,"profession":"Plumbing","image":require('../assets/images/plumbing.png')},
                    {"key":2,"profession":"Electricity","image":require('../assets/images/electricity.png')},
                    {"key":3,"profession":"Gardening", "image": require('../assets/images/gardening.png')},
                    {"key":4,"profession":"Woodworking", "image": require('../assets/images/wood.png')},
                    {"key":5,"profession":"House Cleaning", "image": require('../assets/images/cleaing.png')},
                    {"key":1,"profession":"Plumbing","image":require('../assets/images/plumbing.png')},
                    {"key":2,"profession":"Electricity","image":require('../assets/images/electricity.png')},
                    {"key":3,"profession":"Gardening", "image": require('../assets/images/gardening.png')},
                    {"key":4,"profession":"Woodworking", "image": require('../assets/images/wood.png')},
                    {"key":5,"profession":"House Cleaning", "image": require('../assets/images/cleaing.png')},
                    {"key":6,"profession":"Car Repairs", "image": require('../assets/images/car.png')}
                  ]
    }


  }





  onPress = async () => {
    // alert('test')
    await this.props.navigation.navigate('Professionals')
  }
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    const tileDimensions = calcTileDimensions(width, 3)  // -> change this number and see!

    return (
      <View>


       <Button title='test' onPress={this.onPress}> test </Button>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        {this.state.tiles.map((object,index) => Item({...tileDimensions, text:object.profession, the_key: index, image:object.image}))}   
      </ScrollView>





      </View>

    );
  }
}

function Item ({size, margin, text , the_key, image}) {
  return (
  <View style={[styles.itemText]} key={the_key}  onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
  <TouchableOpacity 
    style={[styles.item, {width: size, height: size, marginHorizontal: margin, backgroundColor:  "transparent"}]}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
    onPress={this.onPress}>
    <Image source={image}/>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
  )
};

const calcTileDimensions = (deviceWidth, tpr) => {
  const margin = deviceWidth / (tpr * 10);
  const size = (deviceWidth - margin * (tpr * 2)) / tpr;
  return { size, margin };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap", 
    paddingBottom:20, 
    paddingTop:20
  },
  item: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderColor: "black", borderRadius: 10, borderWidth:1
  },

  itemText: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    "alignItems": "center",
    "justifyContent": "center",
    "paddingBottom":5,
    "fontSize": 20

  }
});
export default HomeScreen
```

I expected to be routed to the `ProfessionalsScreen` but nothing happened. Is it possible that the list is rendering too quickly?

Comment: are you using react-navigation?

Comment: yes I am, navigation is working perferctly for pressables outside the map function

Comment: try changing your Item function to arrow function... . Item =() =>{}

Comment: I have tried this previously and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the OnPress function is out of scope for the Item Component, you should pass the bound onPress function (or arrow function ) as props to the item function  and then use it like this

```
function Item ({size, margin, text , the_key, image ,SOMEONPRESSFUNCTION}) {
  return (
  <View style={[styles.itemText]} key={the_key}  onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
  <TouchableOpacity 
    style={[styles.item, {width: size, height: size, marginHorizontal: margin, backgroundColor:  "transparent"}]}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
    onPress={ONPRESSFUNCTION}>
    <Image source={image}/>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
  )
};
```